# How do I set fontsize for ax.pie() properly in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've got this code that just puts several `ax.pie()` on the top of each other, but I want to extend it later. The code looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as mc
import numpy as np
import random as rnd
import pandas as pd
from typing import Tuple, List, Generator, T, Union
def dataframe() -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = pd.read_csv("https://github.com/selva86/datasets/raw/master/mtcars.csv")
    df = df.corr()
    return df
def rgb_to_hex(rgb: Tuple[float, float, float]) -> str:
    rgb = [int(round(i * 256)) for i in rgb[0:3]]
    rgb = [i-1 if i == 256 else i for i in rgb]
    return '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(*rgb)
def colors(ax: plt.Axes,
           df: pd.DataFrame,
           cmap: str) -> List[str]:
    mesh = ax.pcolormesh(df, cmap=cmap)
    colors = [i for i in mesh.cmap(mesh.norm(mesh.get_array()))]
    colors = [rgb_to_hex(i) for i in colors]
    return colors
def list_split(lst: List[T],
               n: int) -> Generator[List[T], None, None]:
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]
def radial_locs(amount: int) -> Generator[Tuple[T], None, None]:
    locs = np.radians(np.linspace(0, 360, amount, endpoint = False))
    for i, j in zip(np.around(np.sin(locs), 5),
                    np.around(np.cos(locs), 5)):
        yield i, j 
class Plotter:
    def __init__(self,
                 ax: plt.Axes,
                 df: pd.DataFrame,
                 cmap: str,
                 total_radius: float,
                 empty_radius: float,
                 empty_color: Union[str, tuple, float],
                 x_labels: Union[bool, list],
                 y_labels: Union[bool, list],
                 x_labels_size: float,
                 y_labels_size: float,
                 angle: float) -> None:
        # pass user-provided arguments
        self.ax = ax
        self.df = df
        self.cmap = cmap
        self.total_radius = total_radius
        self.empty_radius = empty_radius
        self.empty_color = empty_color
        if x_labels:
            if isinstance(x_labels, list):
                self.x_labels = x_labels 
            else:
                self.x_labels = df.columns.tolist()
        else:
            self.x_labels = []
        if y_labels:
            if isinstance(y_labels, list):
                self.y_labels = y_labels
            else:
                self.y_labels = df.index.values.tolist()
        else:
            self.y_labels = []
        self.x_labels_size = x_labels_size
        self.y_labels_size = y_labels_size
        self.angle = angle
        # pass everything else
        self.x_size = df.shape[0]
        self.y_size = df.shape[1]
        self.colors = colors(ax, df, cmap)
        ax.clear()
    def radial_heatmap(self) -> None:
        radii = np.linspace(self.total_radius/self.y_size,
                            self.total_radius, self.y_size)
        radii = (radii+self.empty_radius)[::-1]
        color_lists = list_split(self.colors, self.x_size)
        for index, (radius, color_list) in enumerate(zip(radii, color_lists)):
            labels = self.x_labels if index == 0 else None
            (self.ax).pie([10/self.x_size] * self.x_size,
                          radius = radius, colors = color_list[::-1],
                          startangle = self.angle,
                          labels = labels,
                          labeldistance = 1.03,
                          textprops={'fontsize': 16})
        (self.ax).pie([100], radius = self.empty_radius,
                      colors = [self.empty_color])
        (self.ax).axis("equal")       
def radial_heatmap(ax: plt.Axes,
                   df: pd.DataFrame,
                   cmap: str,
                   total_radius: float,
                   empty_radius: float,
                   empty_color: Union[str, tuple, float] = "white",
                   x_labels: Union[bool, list] = True,
                   y_labels: Union[bool, list] = True,
                   x_labels_size: float = 14,
                   y_labels_size: float = 14,
                   angle: float = 90) -> None:
    heatmap = Plotter(ax, df, cmap, total_radius,
                      empty_radius, empty_color,
                      x_labels, x_labels_size,
                      y_labels, y_labels_size,
                      angle)
    heatmap.radial_heatmap()
def main():
    df = dataframe()
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20, 20))
    radial_heatmap(ax, df, 'RdYlGn', 5, 3,
                   x_labels_size = 16)
    plt.savefig("radial_test_0.png")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As you see, in line 85, I've set the `fontsize` of the labels to 16. However, if I change it to `self.x_labels_size` to set it according to the size specified in line 110, which is also precisely 16, no labels will be displayed at all. What kind of problem am I facing here, and how should I fix it?

Comment: Why do you separate `labels_size` as __x__ and __y__ ? Why don't you use only one variable for passing font size ? You can set font size as `rcParams` and it would be much easier for you.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've removed the line with textprops and called `plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 50` before the call to `radial_heatmap()` in `main()`, and it's working brilliantly.

Comment: Check the answer, your mistake was order of parameters in `Plotter` instance. You have misplaced `x_labels_size` and  `y_labels`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the value of `self.x_labels_size` it will be `True`. When you are creating `Plotter` instance, you are giving parameters in incorrect order . It should be like this :

```
heatmap = Plotter(ax, df, cmap, total_radius,
                  empty_radius, empty_color,
                  x_labels, y_labels,
                  x_labels_size, y_labels_size,
                  angle)
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally Matplotlib uses a value from `matplotlibrc` for the size of the labels and the numeric labels: `font.size`. Using only this value, they are both either large or small.

This is not exactly the answer to your specific problem, but (in general), when trying to have numeric labels of a different size, you have to iterate over one of the values returned by calling `ax.pie()`: `autotexts`.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("https://github.com/selva86/datasets/raw/master/mpg_ggplot2.csv")
df = df.groupby('class').size()

params = {
    'font.family': 'Roboto Mono',
    'font.size': 25,
    
    'figure.figsize': (7, 7),
    'figure.dpi': 100
}
mpl.rcParams.update(mpl.rcParamsDefault)
mpl.rcParams.update(params)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes(rect = [0, 0, 1, 1])

_, _, autotexts = ax.pie(
    df,
    labels = df.index, # None here turns off labels, the text outside pie chart.
    autopct = '%1.1f%%', # Hidden if None
    startangle = 90
)

for text in autotexts:
    text.set_fontsize(8)

plt.show()
```

[image]